# Array Manipulation in Crystal Reports 2008 - Not displaying correct result

Tags: arrays, vbscript, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, formula-editor

I am very new to Crystal Reports (2days old), I am trying to loop through an `array` of `strings` and check for a particular value. If that value exists modify that value.

I am doing all this in the record selection formula. But the code is not behaving as expected. Please let me know the issue with the code:-

```
Local numberVar i;

For i := 1 to ubound({?Partner_Name}) Do

(

     IF {?Partner_Name}[i] = 'Lincoln - MN' Then
          {?Partner_Name}[i] = 'Lincoln'
     Else If{?Partner_Name}[i] = 'LINCOLN - UT' Then
          {?Partner_Name}[i] = 'LINCOLN'
     Else
          {?Partner_Name}[i] = {?Partner_Name}[i]
);

{Command.PARTNER_NAME} = {?Partner_Name}
```

Any Help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any error? or not getting require ouptpu? what is your exact issue? be specific

Comment: @Siva - I am not getting the required output, It is not changing values as per the criteria

Comment: You can't reassign a value to a `parameter field`.  Moreover, you can't use `UBound()` on a `parameter field`.  What are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This will 'compile':

```
Local Numbervar i;
// assign multi-select parameter to string array
Local Stringvar Array partners := {?Partner_Name};

For i := 1 To Ubound(partners) Do (
    Select partners[i]
    Case "Lincoln - MN": partners[i]:="Lincoln"
    Case "LINCOLN - UT": partners[i]:="LINCOLN"
);

// this line will raise an exception; you can't reassign the value
{?Partner_Name}:=partners;

// display the value
Join(partners, ", ");

...
```

Comment: haaaa you are `9 sec` faster than me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is one workaround here.. This is not a tested one. Instead of storing the values in parameter field.  Try a different way.

1. Create a parameter that with multiple input selected.
2. Then create a array and write the code:

```
Local numberVar i;
Local StringVar array a;
Local StringVar array b:=join({?Partner_Name},",");

// Not sure which function works here currently don't have CR tool
For i := 1 to ubound(b) Do    
(

     IF {?Partner_Name}[i] = 'Lincoln - MN' Then
          a := 'Lincoln'
     Else If{?Partner_Name}[i] = 'LINCOLN - UT' Then
          a := 'LINCOLN'
     Else
          a := {?Partner_Name}[i]

);
```

3. Now in selection formula use like this:

```
{Command.PARTNER_NAME} IN a
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Your code won't work.  You can't assign values to a `parameter field` in that manner, nor can you get its `ubound()`.

Comment: @Siva - Thanks for the code. But it is giving me a error "The ) is missing". I am pretty sure all braces are complete. Not sure what the error indicates

Comment: @craig - If not this way then how can we assign the values to a parameter field? I am able to get ubound() correctly I checked.

Comment: Still quite a few errors with this answer. First, `Join()` returns a string, not an array. 2. Your `a` variable is an array but you treat it like a string during your assignments in the for-loop. 3. You don't need the `b` variable at all... `ubound()` works fine with a multi-response parameter.